# Timers aren't updating in UITableView iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using countdown times in tableView for each cell as shown in the image.

[TableView with Countdown timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oymnC.png)

If I use the following code for a simple label in the controller, all works fine.

```
var duration = 0.0
func clock(){
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self](Timer) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            strongSelf.duration -= 0.01
            let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
            formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
            formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour,.minute,.second]
            formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
            strongSelf.timerLabel.text = formatter.string(from: strongSelf.duration)
        })
    }
```

But if I write similar for tableViewCell, this only shows values, but not updating them.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"myTimer", for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
        let label = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(13) as? UILabel
        milisecondsClock(index: indexPath.row, label: label!)
        return cell!
    }

    func milisecondsClock(index: Int,label: UILabel){
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self](Timer) in

            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            strongSelf.myList[index] -= 0.01
            let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
            formatter.unitsStyle = .positional
            formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour,.minute,.second]
            formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
            label.text = formatter.string(from: strongSelf.myList[index])
        })
    }
```

How do I show the timer in tableview with real-time countdown?

Comment: use **self.tableView.reloadData()** where it is necessary

Comment: You need to reload the cell after updating the lable.text. Add `strongSelf.tableView. reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)`.

Comment: I assume you've checked that the timer is being fired and that the label isn't `nil`. Shouldn't changing `label.text` happen on the main thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/43946446/285190

Comment: Could you please print the formatter.string(from: strongSelf.myList[index]) value, I did try with myList and work as well?

Answer (score 0):

Table cells are not updated because timers created at `millisecondsClock` have no owner object and are immideately deleted by ARC. You should store your timers in your view controller the same way you store `myList`. You can find more info about ARC at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

You also shouldn't pass `UILabel` into `millisecondsClock` method because cells are **reused** by `UITableView`. That means that the same cell and `UILabel` inside that cell may be used several times to render contant at different index paths. In your case that means that several timers may simultaneously update the same label. I think you should use `func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?` inside timer block to get the correct cell to update the time.